# Alfresco: associated documents trigger folder rules

Tags: alfresco

We are facing a problem with regard to associating documents in Alfresco.

The case:

1. folder A, has a rule R that triggers only when content is created
2. a document A is created in folder A and triggers the rule correctly
3. the document A is being updated and a document B (from folder B) is associated to A ussing a custom aspect/association
4. document B triggers the folder's A rule!

Folder A and B are completely irrelevant.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Associations are stored as `children` of the file's node.

So if the rule is set to trigger on subfolders, the file with the associations will be handled as a folder and the associated files as its containing files.

Simple solution: uncheck the trigger on subfolders option in the rule's settings

Comment: Thanks, the proposed solution fixed the problem, still this is not an coherent functionality...